I am trying to access a model using a foreign key in another model in the same models.py file. But I am getting a name "model_name" not defined error
class chaiVariety(models.Model):
    CHAI_TYPE_CHOICE = [
        ('ML', 'MASALA'),
        ('GR', 'GINGER'),
        ('KL', 'KIWI'),
        ('PL', 'PLAIN'),
        ('EL', 'ELAICHI'),
    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='chais/')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CHAI_TYPE_CHOICE)
    description = models.TextField(default=' ')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    

    #One to many
    class chaiReview(models.Model):
        chai = models.ForeignKey(chaiVariety, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        rating = models.IntegerField()
        comment = models.TextField()
        date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} review for {self.chai.name}'

As I am trying to access the chaiVariety model inside the chaiReview using a foreign key, I am getting the following error:
Name 'chaiVariety' is not defined

is both class in same models.py file or in different.

You can just put quotes around the model name if it comes after the model accessing it such as: "chaiVariety"

I believe you are trying something like 'chaiReview.objects.all().first().chaiVariety'. You have to use the field name in the second model, not the foreign key model name. e.g. 'chaiReview.objects.all().first().chai'.
